# change permission to read write and execute

Tags: permissions

How do I change the following folder shown below "manage" to read write and execute permission? What should I do?

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 22 08:15 /var/lib/iHRIS/sites/manage
```

I used the `ls -ld` to view the permission rights of the folder.

Answer (score 4):

Run `sudo chmod a+rwx /var/lib/iHRIS/sites/manage` to give read, write and execute to all who wants to access it.

Note: a=All (u=User, g=Group) and rwx is Read, Write and eXecute. + means add permission, - means remove permission.