# Having issue with chown

Tags: chown

I am trying to run a game on Wine, and for some reason after I run it one time, the files are locked after the first run and I can only open it using a Root account.
I want to change ownership so that I can open the file with a regular account. I tried:

> sudo chown -R Vince:evelauncher.sh

and I got this feedback:

> chown: missing operand after ‘Vince:evelauncher.sh’
>   Try 'chown --help' for more information.

and of course the "help" menu wasn't much help lol

Comment: Others have already answered your question. I don't think you need the recursive `-R` option in this case, assuming `evelauncher.sh` is a file and not a directory containing other files. I would be careful of using `-R` option. Changing ownership of system folders and files can make a system unbootable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out user68186. I'm not sure what I should use in place of R? ALso just FYI, the evelauncher.sh file is not the only file in that folder showing as locked. SHould I try again and use the R option, but change ownership of the whole folder instead of just the evelauncher.sh file? I should also ad that the game is running fine now with the command I used...although I have not tried rebooting.

Comment: If it works let it be. Rebooting should not change anything. You may also give yourself (and others) permission to read, write, and execute the file without changing ownership. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/470831/change-permission-to-read-write-and-execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax of `chown` command is:

```
sudo chown user:group file
```

so you have to use it like:

```
sudo chown -R Vince:  evelauncher.sh
```

Pay attention to the space, by leaving the group section it will be automatically set to your primary group.

Comment: you beat me by only a few seconds gosh darn thee.

Comment: Yep :D :D :D ...

Comment: It was a valiant effort Ravexin, I wish I could mark them both as the solution! It's amazing how little details like that make all the difference with code. Thanks! I'll try to be more detail oriented in the future:)...EDIT: wait I thought Thomas was first because he was showing on top. I changed the marked solution to the first responder

Comment: @vince I'm Glad that it was helpful ;)

Comment: Just a minor correction: if you do USER: it assumes you want user and group to be the same.  The extra space you added does nothing, and is unnecessary.

Comment: @ThomasWard I checked it again, when you use `USER:` it assumes that you want the USER's primary group, not a group with same name as USER. I used extra space to make sure the OP sees the different :-)

Comment: @Ravexina in 99% of cases the 'primary group' is the usergroup made for the user.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yeah, but I actually changed my primary group to something else to test it. Again file's group became my primary group which wasn't same as my username.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo chown -R Vince:evelauncher.sh` is an incomplete command.

The proper usage of `chown` is as follows:

```
chown [options] USER[:GROUP] file
```

(in your command, `-R` for recursive is an option)

Your line does not put a space between the `Vince:` (user and group designator) and the file name, so it doesn't work.  You need to use spaces such that you end up with this:

```
sudo chown -R Vince: evelauncher.sh
```